# Can we get a better diff for retags?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, revision-history

At the moment, when someone adds one tag to a question, like

this: <kbd>c++</kbd> <kbd>casting</kbd> <kbd>pointers</kbd>
to this: <kbd>c++</kbd> <kbd>casting</kbd> <kbd>pointers</kbd> <kbd>c++-faq</kbd>

The edit history/suggested edit sometimes shows a diff like you added and removed one more tag, e.g.:

c++ <strike>casting</strike> pointers **casting c++-faq**

Can we get this spurious non-change removed there?

Comment: I assume this is because the tag scores get recalculated and ordered from most common to least common. I don't see a problem with it.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: Quite likely that's what happens behind the scene. Still, allowing this implementation detail to leak into the diff adds unneccessary noise.

Comment: Either that or the original revision had a synonym of `casting`, rather than `casting` itself, and the edit resulted in the synonym being changed to the canonical version of the tag.